# Combobox show text properly

Tags: gwt, combobox, smartgwt

I have a combo box that when I open it should show text like
[image: this]

However I get something like 
[image: this]

with the scrollbar set to middle. Thing is sometimes for the same values it shows properly
and sometimes it shows from middle(for same value).

I want it to show properly like in the first image and I've tried a couple of things but with no succes.

```
itemSection.setHoverAlign(Alignment.LEFT);

itemSection.setTextAlign(Alignment.LEFT);

itemSection.setAlign(Alignment.LEFT);
```

... and other irelevand stuff ...

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks alot!

Comment: Can you show a little bit more of your code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not getting wrong, You want to set your scrollbar at particular position. FOr that you need to ovverride the css of that and try to set scrollbar position to 0. So that your problem will get solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with any kind of selections box is, that the boxes display and behave completely different across browsers. The older the browser the worse it handles long texts in selection boxes (some just truncate the text). I suggest to keep the displayed text as short as possible. That way you can avoid this problem.

If you really need long description, you can try to add a tooltip to every entry. Or use a different widget to make the select from, e.g. some custom widget in a separate dialog...

Comment: This is a SmartGWT combo box, so it's not a simple HTML `<select>` but a custom widget, using a `<div>` for the popup list.